# Django buttons loading more posts on click

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

I want to implement the loading of the following posts in the news on a button click using ajax. So far it turned out to load the same number of posts when pressed. Those. I immediately see 5, then I pressed another 5. And so on. I want to make sure that after the first 5 posts, they are loaded further not by 5, but by 8. But it just doesn't work. And I don't know which direction to go to get it.

views.py

```
class NewsView(ListView):
    template_name="mebelain/news.html"
    queryset = News.objects.all().order_by("-date_news")

class NewsJsonListView(View):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        upper = kwargs.get('num_news')
        lower = upper - 5
        all_news = list(News.objects.values()[lower:upper])
        return JsonResponse({'all_news':all_news})
```

urs.py

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('news', views.NewsView.as_view(),name='news'),
  path('json_news/<int:num_news>/', views.NewsJsonListView.as_view(),name = "json_news")
]
```

script.js

```js
let visible = 5

const hadleGetData = () => {
  $.ajax({
    url: `/json_news/${visible}/`,
    type: 'get',
    success: function(response) {
      const data = response.all_news
      data.map(news => {
        console.log(news.id)
      })
    },
    error: function(error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  })
}

hadleGetData()
window.addEventListener("load", News)

function News() {
  const loadBtn = document.getElementById('load-btn')
  loadBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    visible += 5
    hadleGetData()
  })
}
```

What do I need to fix so that I can load posts as described above?

Comment: Did you push the button before that you get response from your first request?

Comment: @KIN1991 now 5 posts are loaded at once.
Then by pressing the button 5 more, etc.
but after the first five I would like to download 8